# How to code a built-in Javascript function to a recursive function (using global variables)

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, global-variables

I am brand new to JavaScript and am stuck on a string.replace program that requires use of recursive functions and global variables. The purpose is to replace any instances of a word/phrase (`sub_key`) with another word/phrase (`sub_value`), then pad the ends of the sentence with the `sub_value`.

This is my base code:

```js
function Obscure(sub_key, sub_value, sentence) {
  var obscuredSentence = sentence.replace(sub_key, sub_value);
  var obscuredSentence = sub_value + " " + obscuredSentence + " " + sub_value;
  return obscuredSentence;
}

console.log(Obscure("the", "the goat", "I want the money")

    //--> "the goat I want the goat money the goat" );
```

However, I need to write a recursive function that runs twice (and only twice) in order to continue replacing the `sub_key` with the sub_value in the case that the `sub_value` also contains the `sub_key` (e.g. "the goat"). My final sentence should read "the goat I want the goat goat money the goat".

I tried this code, but it overflows the stack (ha):

```js
function Obscure(sub_key, sub_value, sentence) {
  var obscuredSentence = sentence.replace(sub_key, sub_value);

  for (var count = 1; count < 2; count++) {
    return Obscure(sub_key, sub_value, sentence);
  }

  var obscuredSentence = sub_value + " " + obscuredSentence + " " + sub_value;
  return obscuredSentence;
}

console.log(Obscure("the", "the goat", "I want the money"));
//"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (line 2 in function Obscure)"
```

Any help/advice is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55317218/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: thanks @mplungjan -- does this edit make my question more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small change in your code which is below and it should resolve your problem if you want to execute it only two times.

```js
var count = 1;

function Obscure(sub_key, sub_value, sentence) {
  var obscuredSentence = sentence.replace(sub_key, sub_value);

  for (; count < 2;) {
    count++;
    return Obscure(sub_key, sub_value, obscuredSentence);
  }

  var obscuredSentence = sub_value + " " + obscuredSentence + " " + sub_value;
  return obscuredSentence;
}

console.log(Obscure("the", "the goat", "I want the money"));
```

Comment: Hi @Ankur -- thanks, this solves my overflow issue, but still doesn't give me the necessary solution (It outputs "the goat I want the goat money the goat" when I need "the goat I want *the goat* goat money the goat" -- it needs to run the function one more time to replace the "the" in "the goat" with "the goat" again).

Comment: I have updated the code snippet replaced sentence with obscuredSentence, just have a look and l hope this time your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`for(` isn't recursive, it's iterative.

You want two functions: a helper function with the recursive call, and another, only taking care of padding the ends and calling the recursive fn. Something like

```js
function obscureInside(sub_key, sub_value, sentence, repetitions) {
  if (repetitions <= 0) {
    return sentence;
  }

  var sentenceAfterSingleRun = sentence.replace(sub_key, sub_value);
  return obscureInside(sub_key, sub_value, sentenceAfterSingleRun, repetitions - 1);

}

function obscure(sub_key, sub_value, sentence) {
  var obscuredSentence = obscureInside(sub_key, sub_value, sentence, 2);
  return sub_value + " " + obscuredSentence + " " + sub_value;
}

console.log(obscure("the", "the goat", "I want the money"));
```